# how to include specific js file in ember.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, ember.js

I added a `.js` file into my `bower_components` folder in my ember app. The file is included in my `ember-cli-build.js` like `app.import('bower_components/script.js')`. The app is working correctly on localhost but when i try to upload my app to `heroku` i got the error message `no such file or directory script`.

My question is where shall i put the `script.js` file? Shall i import it somewhere in my app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`bower_components` folder is transient and is not good place for your file.

Move `script.js` to `vendor` folder

Answer (score 3):

This is covered in the [documentation](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/addons-and-dependencies/managing-dependencies/#toc_other-assets), under

**Addons and Dependencies > Managing Dependencies > Other Assets**

---

From the documentation

> ### Other assets
>
> Assets not available as an addon or Bower package should be placed in
>   the `vendor` folder in your project.

---

So your `script.js` would go under `vendor/`. And then in your `ember-cli-build.js` file, you would do a `app.import('vendor/script.js')`.